# Get name of title of a tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a copy of Notepad. Here, I want to get the name of the title of the tkinter window.

I need it because if the title of the window is **Untitled - Notepad** then I want to quit the program directly but if the title name is not **Untitled - Notepad** then I want to display message if you want to really quit the program.

**How can I do so?**

Comment: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.title-method

Comment: Its only about to set the name of title not the get the title of the window

Comment: from the link above: *...or gets the window title*.

Comment: Read text from link again. There is "Sets or **gets** the window title. "  Some functions in tkinter gives you value if you don't use parameter(s) - `title = root.title()`

Comment: Awwww..... man thats awesome. It worked like a charm. Thank you very much CommonSense and furas

Comment: Don't read the title of your window to determine whether the file you are currently editing is "unnamed", or has already been saved, or has been changed since the last save. Instead, keep this information in some dedicated attributes of your editor class, and use _those_ to determine the title of the editor window. Otherwise, it will be a mess if you ever decide to change the format of the title. Also, what if the file _is_ literally named "Untitled"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use:

```
if root.title() == "Untitled - Notepad":
    # do something
```

But that might not be the best way to do it.
@tobias_k put it well:

> Don't read the title of your window to determine whether the file you are currently editing is "unnamed", or has already been saved, or has been changed since the last save. Instead, keep this information in some dedicated attributes of your editor class, and use those to determine the title of the editor window. Otherwise, it will be a mess if you ever decide to change the format of the title. Also, what if the file is literally named "Untitled"?